# Background Image not sized to specified width & height

Tags: html, css

I have a link tag for which I want to add a background image. Now I specified a width and height for the background which is the width and height of the image. The problem is that the browser does not size the background image to those specified sizes, it ignores them. 
Here is my code: Any suggestions?

```
<div align="center" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial,   
Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();" title="UK referral system credits" 
     style="background: url(images/earnings.png) no-repeat center; width: 150px; 
     height: 40px;">Show my earnings</a>
<iframe id="toggleText" style="display: none;" frameborder="0" height="700" 
    src="http://v4m.mobi/cwf/facebook/uk/user_temp_credits_earned.php"; target="_blank"   
    align="center" width="300" scrolling="Auto"; bgcolor="#C9D3DE"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Thank You

Comment: height & width will not work on inline elements. style your a with `a {display: block}` and make it float. :)

Comment: Thank you islandmyth, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "display: block" like this:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();" title="UK referral system credits" 
     style="background: url(images/earnings.png) no-repeat center; width: 150px; 
     height: 40px; display: block;">Show my earnings</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any downsides to this? especially with regard to browser compatibility?

Comment: I work the buttons in my pages like this and i dont have any compatibility issues. Once you uploaded your page to your server you can test compatibility in different browsers and os with Adobe Browser Lab https://browserlab.adobe.com/. I use it and i highly recomend it, its also free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-size syntax

Below might be helpful
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should move your style rules into an external .css file. Not only will it make your code easier to read, but it's a better separation of concerns.

Secondly, unless you're using the CSS3 `background-size` property, you cannot explicitly set the size of a background image. It will be 100% of the original images size, and completely separate to the size of the element it is the background of.

To use `background-size`, try this: `background-size: 150px 40px;`. Be aware that this will not work in IE8 or lower though.

Comment: Thank you. How do you suggest I go about this-that is, I have a clickable link that I want to add a background image for. What is the best way to make the background image display its full size(currenly it only shows the size of the text, hence a small portion of the background.

Comment: If you don't want to use the CSS3 method, then you must either make the `#displayText` the same size as the image - for which you'd need to set `display: block` on it. The other option is to make the background image smaller to fit the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
background-size: 150px 40px;
```

Comment: Works for me http://dabblet.com/gist/2769305 Though it really would be better to separate the HTML from the CSS